# C# make specific ListBox item text bold and remove some items

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I remove the "red marked" area and make the "blue marked" area bold in my listbox?
And I would like to have two empty items between the item MAT and LBL1. How do I make it possible?

[image]

I tryed:
No idea how.. but try to bold it...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    private void ListBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lb1 = (ListBox)sender;
        var itemText = lb1.Items[e.Index].ToString();
        var textBold = FontStyle.Bold;

        // Make index bold from Client to MAT(or Client to first empty item)

        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to use selected index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a solution. Delete some items and make some bold. It works fine!

> ```
>     void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
>     {
>         e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
>         int leading = 1;
>         int leftMargin = 25;
>         int topMargin = 25;
>
>         // a few simple formatting options..
>         StringFormat FmtRight = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Far };
>         StringFormat FmtLeft = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near };
>         StringFormat FmtCenter = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near };
>
>         StringFormat fmt = FmtLeft;
>
>         //set bold for the first 6 lines
>         using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 12f, FontStyle.Bold))
>         {
>             SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString("_|", Font);
>             float h = sz.Height + leading;
>
>             for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
>                 e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox9.Items[i].ToString(), font,
>                 Brushes.Black, leftMargin, topMargin + h * i, fmt);
>         }
>
>         //make the rest regular
>         using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 12f))
>         {
>             SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString("_|", Font);
>             float h = sz.Height + leading;
>
>             for (int i2 = 6; i2 < listBox9.Items.Count; i2++)
>                 e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox9.Items[i2].ToString(), font,
>                 Brushes.Black, leftMargin, topMargin + h * i2, fmt);
>         }
>     }
>
>         listBox9.BeginUpdate();            
>
>         string MAT = "MAT:";
>         string KNR = "KNR";
>         string SPANNUNG = "SPANNUNG";
>
>         //select the item, from where the deletion should start
>         for (int i = 0; i < listBox9.Items.Count; i++)
>         {
>             if (listBox9.Items[i].ToString().Contains(KNR))
>             {
>                 listBox9.SetSelected(i + 1, true);
>             }
>             else if (listBox9.Items[i].ToString().Contains(MAT))
>             {
>                 listBox9.ClearSelected();
>                 listBox9.SetSelected(i + 1, true);
>             }
>             else if (listBox9.Items[i].ToString().Contains(SPANNUNG))
>             {
>                 listBox9.ClearSelected();
>                 listBox9.SetSelected(i + 1, true);
>             }
>         }
>
>         //select all items between "SPANNUNG" and "LBL1"
>         for (int i2 = listBox9.SelectedIndex; i2 < listBox9.Items.Count; i2++)
>         {
>             listBox9.SetSelected(i2, true);
>             if (listBox9.Items[i2 + 1].ToString().Contains("LBL1"))
>             {
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>
>         // delete all selected items between "SPANNUNG" and "LBL1", that I don't need
>         var selected = listBox9.SelectedItems.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
>         var selectedIndices = new List<int>(listBox9.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>());
>         selectedIndices.Reverse();
>         selectedIndices.ForEach(index => listBox9.Items.RemoveAt(index));
>
>         // insert to spaces between "SPANNUNG" and "LBL1"
>         for (int i3 = 0; i3 < listBox9.Items.Count; i3++)
>         {
>             if (listBox9.Items[i3].ToString().Contains("LBL1"))
>             {
>                 listBox9.SetSelected(i3, true);
>                 listBox9.Items.Insert(listBox9.SelectedIndex, "");
>                 listBox9.Items.Insert(listBox9.SelectedIndex, "");
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>
>         listBox9.ClearSelected();
>         listBox9.EndUpdate();
> ```

Comment: Please just edit your existing question if you tried something new.
An answer is not the place for another question.

Comment: I solved it: if (listBox9.Items[i2+1].ToString().Contains("LBL1")) is correct. If (I2 == LBLindex) don't work. Need now a way to bold the first 5 items.

Comment: What you can do now is the following: Edit this answer to actually be an answer (replace the second question by the stuff you just figured out). And mark it as `accepted`, so others know what to do.